# Hosting a Django application using Railway: MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: python, django, static, web-hosting, static-linking

I am trying to publicly host my portfolio website under my domain name: [www.floriskruger.com](http://www.floriskruger.com). I have build my application using Django and I am using Railway to communicate with my GitHub profile in order to deploy this site. Everything seems to be working fine except for that none of my .css and .js files are linking properly to my website.

[image: My site without any css or js linked to it]

This is what the links look like within my html file.

```
<!-- CSS Styling -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/css/home.css" type="text/css">

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="/templates/javascript/home.js" type="text/javascript" defer>
```

The error that I am getting within the web console states "Refused to apply style from 'https://www.floriskruger.com/templates/css/home.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled." which makes me think that there is some sort of linking error with how the files are configured? However I did not have this problem on a local host.

[image: screenshot of web console]

This is how my files are configured within my project

[image]

I will also provide how I have my settings.py configured for my static files.

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.floriskruger.com', 'onlineportfolio-production.up.railway.app/']
    
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
]

STATIC_URL = 'staticfiles/'

STATIC_ROOT = "/www/floriskruger.com/staticfiles/"

MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
```

And within urls.py I also have

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Also try to make use of the whitenoise package with: pip install whitenoise. This makes the entire process of serving static files on a public server much easier. Also be sure to add whatever version of whitenoise you get to your requirements.txt within your django project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like in your *settings.py* you are setting your static root to “staticfiles/“. However your static files are stored inside the Templates folder.

You can fix this error by simply moving your **templates** folder inside of the **staticfiles** folder.

The tree for your staticfiles folder would look a little like this.

[image]

Keep in mind you will need to make the appropriate changes to all of the paths referencing the static files. Best of luck.